# Why is the output in clion displaying smiley faces instead of characters?

Tags: c, clion

[image: The code as well as the output screen]

I was expecting it to result the same thing back but for some reason its just not and displaying smiley faces. Running a normal getchar and putchar works fine and it gives out the expected output.
Even entering single character just returns a smiley face as well. I'm new to c and clion so I would appreciate the help.

Edit: I figured out the cause of the problem. The bracket on the while loop were not used correctly. But still don't understand why smiley faces?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int c;

    while ((c = getchar() != EOF))
        putchar(c);


}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And [don't post images of *any* text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: The expression `(c = getchar() != EOF)` is really the same as `(c = (getchar() != EOF))`. Please take some time to think about the parentheses and their placement.

Comment: Yeah I put up and edit where I said that i understood the paranthesis but what about the smiley faces. Just wondering why they are a thing?

Comment: @AryNsachan do you know what the values of `(c = (getchar() != EOF))` is?

Answer (score 4):

You have

```c
( c = getchar() != EOF )
```

instead of

```c
( c = getchar() ) != EOF
```

This means you are assigning the result of the inequality to `c` (instead of the result of `getchar()`), and the inequality returns either `0` (at EOF) or `1` (otherwise).

So you are printing character 1. Depending on your console's code page, it could be U+263A WHITE SMILING FACE, "☺".

[image: The start of the cp437 character set]

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @AryNsachan f so, check the mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is very simple.

In your code you always print character with code `1` (unless `c == EOF` when it will `0`) as you assign `c` with the result if the comparison  `getchar()) != EOF` which can be only `0` or `1`. Your code can be written as `while(c=(getchar()!=EOF))`

In your code page it is a smiling face `☺`

You need to assign `c` first, then compare:

```
int main() 
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

BTW it is very good candidate for a warning, but unfortunately, GCC and Clang do not emit it

Comment: Re "*it is very good candidate for a warning*", Well, `while(c=getchar()!=EOF)` would have warned, but the extra set of parens the OP provided signal "I really meant to do that" and silences the warning.

Comment: @ikegami it is. It emits similar when bitwise operations are used.